# OSGeo4W and QGIS 2.0

Tags: qgis, installation, osgeo, osgeo4w

I just ran the OSGeo4W installer to update my previous installation and I noticed that it was updating my QGIS installation from 1.8 to 2.0.  I haven't been able to find any information on the web about QGIS 2.0 being released yet.

The installer ran without any issues, but now that it is complete I cannot find executables for QGIS.  The folder for QGIS exists within the `apps` folder under `C:/OSGeo4W/`, but there are no executables in there.

I've already completely uninstalled all OSGeo4W applications and reran the installer using the Express Install option, but I had the same result.

How can I use QGIS and has version 2.0 been released yet?

Comment: QGIS 2.0 is most likely being released after the FOSS4G 2013 conference has ended (http://2013.foss4g.org/). I can imagine that many attendees squash bugs right now and therefore not everything might work perfect.

Comment: That sounds like some of the traffic I found online about this.  What doesn't make sense is why this would be the default installation from the OSGeo4W installer.

Comment: so what happens if you install qgis-dev rather than qgis (stable) -> select advanced install. My QGIS dev still runs normal and updates don't destroy it.

Comment: So I just discovered that the QGIS .exe and .bat files were installed under the `C:/OSGeo4W/bin` directory.  For some reason, I just didn't get any shortcuts on my desktop like I did with all the other apps that were installed with OSGeo4W.  And it is QGIS 2.0.

Comment: it may be a similar thing I've just discovered: I had 1.8 stable and 1.9 master, then upgraded (to 1.8 & 2.0 then 2.1 master) but the program names in the start menu didn't change... hence 1.9 was 2.1 and 1.8 was 2.0. Compounded with the often out-of-sync version number & splash screen, it can be confusing knowing which versions you have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OSGeo4W `Advanced Install`, you can still select the old QGIS 1.08.09 version as an alternative, if you click on the version number.

If you don't get the icons on the screen, your installation was broken at some stage.

There should be installation logs to help you find the reason. You find it in `C:\OSGeo4W\var\log`

Answer (score 2):

The 2.0 packages are in OSGeo4W for testing and wokshop use at FOSS4G.  2.0 will be announced at FOSS4G.

It's not considered a final build yet, or an official release, as there is still some minor things to sort out.

Watch [@qgis](https://twitter.com/qgis), [QGIS on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/pages/QGIS-Quantum-GIS-/298112000235096), [QGIS on Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/109126324126544815949/communities/114776597176808981624), and [qgis.org](http://qgis.org) for the offical release announcement.

You are still free to use the 2.0 package from OSGeo4W just be aware like I said it's not an official release just yet.

Comment: Sadly, the new version is selected by default.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Windows? Win8 is a little different where it puts things.

On the other hand, with the installer, you should have full control of where the executables go.

In the target for the link on my Win8 machine, the detail is     `C:\OSGeo4W\bin\nircmd.exe exec hide C:\OSGeo4W\bin\qgis.bat`

Comment: I did eventually find the .bat and .exe files in the `C:/OsGeo4W/bin` directory and created my own shortcut.  I assumed that those files would be in the qgis directory within the apps folder.